# WKWebView doesn't use URLCache

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, nsurlcache, urlcache

I have an application which use `UIWebView` to show some local content. I Also have a custom `URLCache` to intercept requests and replace them with local content:

```swift
class LocalWebViewCache: URLCache {
    open override func cachedResponse(for request: URLRequest) -> CachedURLResponse? {
    if url.absoluteString.range(of: "http://localhost") != nil {
            return cacheDelegate?.handleRequest(request)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

And I registered this cache in `AppDelagate` as:

```swift
var cache: LocalWebViewCache = LocalWebViewCache(memoryCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024,
                                         diskCapacity: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
                                         diskPath: nil)
URLCache.shared = cache
```

Right now everything is working fine. **BUT** apple rejected the new version of app because I'm using `UIWebView` and it's deprecated, So I replaced the `UIWebView` with `WKWebView` and it seems that webkit doesn't honor the shared cache (`URLCache.shared`).

I tried to intercept `WKWebView` requests with `URLProtocol` and `WKURLSchemeHandler` without any luck.

***I would appreciate any help or suggestion.***

**`URLProtocol` code:**

in `Appdelagate`:

```swift
URLProtocol.registerClass(MyProtocol.self)
```

```swift
class MyProtocol: URLProtocol {
    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        print("canInit: \(String(describing: request.url))")
        return true
    }

    override init(request: URLRequest, cachedResponse: CachedURLResponse?, client: URLProtocolClient?) {
        print("init: \(String(describing: request.url))")

        super.init(request: request, cachedResponse: cachedResponse, client: client)
    }

    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        print("canonicalRequest: \(String(describing: request.url))")

        return request
    }

    override func startLoading() {
        print("startLoading: \(String(describing: request.url))")
    }
}
```

Among all this methods just `canInit(with request: URLRequest)` is getting called which is not very helpful.

**`WKURLSchemeHandler` code:**

```swift
class MySchemeHandler: NSObject, WKURLSchemeHandler {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        print("start: \(String(describing: urlSchemeTask.request.url?.absoluteString))")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        print("stop: \(String(describing: urlSchemeTask.request.url?.absoluteString))")
    }
}
```

```swift
webkit.configuration.setURLSchemeHandler(MySchemeHandler(), forURLScheme: "localhost")

webkit.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "localhost://google.com")!))
```

But neither `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask)` nor `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask)` is getting called.

---

**EDIT 1**: Loading local resource by attaching `localhost://` at the beginning of their url and handle it via `WKURLSchemeHandler`:

```swift
let testStr = """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title></title>
            <link href="localhost://../styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            </head>
            <body>

            <p class="test_class1">This is a paragraph.</p>
            <p class ="test_class2">This is another paragraph.</p>

            </body>
            </html>
    """
```

```swift
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration
            .setURLSchemeHandler(MySchemeHandler(), forURLScheme: "localhost")
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return webView
    }()
```

```swift
webView.loadHTMLString(testStr, baseURL: URL(string: "localhost"))
```

```swift
class MySchemeHandler: NSObject, WKURLSchemeHandler {
    let testCss = """
            @font-face{
                font-family: 'Special';
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                src: url(../fonts/special.ttf);
            }

            .test_class1 {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #007D6E;
                font-family: 'Special' !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            .test_class2 {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #FF7D6E;
                text-align: center !important;
            }
    """

    func webView(_: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        print("start: \(String(describing: urlSchemeTask.request.url?.absoluteString))")

        guard let url = urlSchemeTask.request.url else {
            return
        }

        if url.absoluteString.contains("style.css") {
            let data = Data(testCss.utf8)

            urlSchemeTask.didReceive(URLResponse(url: url,
                                                 mimeType: "text/css",
                                                 expectedContentLength: data
                                                     .count,
                                                 textEncodingName: nil))
            urlSchemeTask.didReceive(data)
            urlSchemeTask.didFinish()
        }
    }

    func webView(_: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        print("stop: \(String(describing: urlSchemeTask.request.url?.absoluteString))")
    }
}
```

In the log I can see that `start` method get triggered for local resources:

```
start: Optional("localhost://../styles/style.css")
start: Optional("localhost://../fonts/special.ttf")
```

But if I remove `localhost://` from `<link href="localhost://../styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
the `start` method won't getting triggered at all.

Comment: What URL scheme do you use in the `MyProtocol` example? 
Also, from my experience, overriding `init` in the `URLProtocol` protocol subclass is not required.

Comment: It doesn't matter what scheme I'm using, it won't work for any scheme. As you can see in the code I used `localhost`, I can use any other custom scheme and it still doesn't work.

Comment: oh, You said in `MyProtocol`. for that I used regular scheme, `http`,`https`

Comment: Setting a handler on the result of calling `WKWebView.configuration` has no effect, since the copy is being returned.
Instead, you should create a new instance of `WKWebViewConfiguration`, set your handler on it and then pass it to `WKWebView.init(frame:, configuration:)`.

Comment: @Russian, It seems that your way is working just for initial request, but it can not capture request sequence include `css`, `js`, `font`... like `URLCache` does

Comment: What types of URLs are used for these resources (css, js, fonts) – absolute or relative?

Comment: They are relative like `../styles/style.css` and I managed to make them trigger `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask)` by adding `localhost` at the beginning of them like: `localhost://styles/style.css`. But is there any way to not do that and still get that method triggred?

Comment: Well, this is strange, because, for instance, when working with custom URL protocols,  "child" resources get requested with the expected custom scheme.
If you can somehow share the content you are trying to load, I could take a look at it later today.

Comment: I think it's because I used `loadHTMLString` like: `wk.loadHTMLString(str, baseURL: URL(string: "localhost"))`. With this and `localhost://styles/style.css` any font inside css file like `src: url(../Fonts/NormalAR.ttf);` trigger that `start` method with url like `localhost://Fonts/NormalAR.ttf` I will update the original question with a sample.

Comment: @Russian I added more info to question.

Comment: I managed to fix my problem based on your first comment. Please add an answer based on that and i will accept it. @Russian

Comment: @medok 
Sorry, I was not able to investigate your problem, but I'm glad you have figured it out yourself. The bounty has ended, but anyway I don't think my answer was worth that much of a reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a handler on the result of calling `WKWebView.configuration` has no effect, since the copy is being returned. Instead, you should create a new instance of `WKWebViewConfiguration`, set your handler on it and then pass it to `WKWebView.init(frame:, configuration:)`:

```
self.schemeHandler = MySchemeHandler()
self.webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.setURLSchemeHandler(self.schemeHandler, 
                                         forURLScheme: "localhost")
    return webConfiguration
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood since iOS 10 WKWebview support AppCache

try this code

```
let webview: WKWebView
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.setValue(true, forKey: "_setOfflineApplicationCacheIsEnabled")
webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

Comment: This throw an exception: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<WKWebViewConfiguration 0x7fc236b0cc40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _setOfflineApplicationCacheIsEnabled.'`

Beside that, I think it's a hidden api and there is a good chance that apple reject the app because of that.

Comment: Using non-public API's will cause the app to be rejected by Apple.

Comment: I see good to know. I hope some one will share the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

`WKNavigationDelegate` has a function to decide how to navigate to a page, you could do filtering and redirects here. Something like this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    // you may need to use .linkActivated depending on how users are navigating
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .other  {
        if let request = navigationAction.request.url {
            if request.absoluteString.hasPrefix("https://somePrefix") {
                // for test
               // guard let localRedirect = URL.init(string: "https://google.com") else {
                guard let localRedirect = URL.init(string: "localhost://someUrl") else {
                    decisionHandler(.allow)
                    return
                }
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                // for test
                // webView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
                webView.loadFileURL(localRedirect, allowingReadAccessTo: localRedirect.deletingLastPathComponent()) // delete last path component if you have other things that the page will load in that directory, like images or css
                return
            }
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

> I've commented out navigating to google as a test, but left the code there so people can see easily how a redirect would work.

Comment: If I misunderstood your objective, please help clarify what your are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not seeking to just see the requests and redirect them to some other url. I'm trying to intercept the requests and replace them with local content. Please see EDIT 1, I have shared some code that shows what I'm trying to do. (codes in edit 1 is working with one minor downside.) Please see my latest comments with @Russain on the original question.